# Xcode/GCC predefined macro for target name?

Tags: xcode, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if there is an Xcode or GCC preprocessor symbol for the target name of the application.

For example if I'm building an application called "MonkeyChicken", is there a preprocessor symbol such that

```
printf( __TARGET_NAME__ )
```

outputs:

```
MonkeyChicken
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is any built-in (gcc has no idea what you're building when you compile a file), but you can always create one using `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` in an xcconfig file (you *are* [using xcconfig](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360), right?) Something like this should work as you indicate above:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = __TARGET_NAME__=\"$(PRODUCT_NAME)\"
```

Comment: My goodness I'm so glad there's an alternative to that damn build panel. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This should be a string, e.g. `__TARGET_NAME__=\"$(PRODUCT_NAME)\"`